# Read .epub file using iphone sdk

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

that is sandip here. i want to know how to read .epub file within our iphone application programmatically . can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ePub format consists of a ZIP file containing various pieces of XML and XHTML; you can read up on the details thereof at the [ePub article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB). To handle the initial decompression of the ZIP archive, you might use one of the solutions linked from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228530/zlib-directly-for-uncompressing-a-zip-folder-for-iphone/3228614#3228614).